# Zombies don't spawn with armor Minecraft

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am trying to code a Minecraft plugin on eclipse that all zombies spawn with max armor and max sword. Howerer they do not spawn with armor and sword. I watched youtube tutorial. Server logs say that plugin is enabled, shows no errors. Help? Here is my code code.

```
public class ChargedCreepersIrZombiaiSuArmor extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {
        @Override
        public void onEnable() {
            this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
        }
        @EventHandler
        public void lol(CreatureSpawnEvent e) {
            if(e.getEntityType() == EntityType.CREEPER) {
                
            
            Creeper creeper = (Creeper) e.getEntity();
            creeper.setPowered(true);
        }
            Zombie zombie = (Zombie) e.getEntity();
        if(e.getEntityType() == EntityType.ZOMBIE) {
            ItemStack maxkardas = new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_SWORD);
            ItemStack maxcap = new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_HELMET);
            ItemStack maxleg = new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_LEGGINGS);
            ItemStack maxboots = new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_BOOTS);
            ItemStack maxchest = new  ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_CHESTPLATE);
            maxkardas.addEnchantment(Enchantment.FIRE_ASPECT, 3); 
            maxkardas.addEnchantment(Enchantment.DAMAGE_ALL, 3); 
            maxkardas.addEnchantment(Enchantment.DURABILITY, 3);
            maxchest.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_FALL, 3);
            maxchest.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_EXPLOSIONS, 3);
            maxchest.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_FIRE, 3);
            maxchest.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_ENVIRONMENTAL, 3);
            maxchest.addEnchantment(Enchantment.DURABILITY, 3);
            maxchest.addEnchantment(Enchantment.THORNS, 3);
            maxchest.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_PROJECTILE, 3);
            maxcap.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_FALL, 3);
            maxcap.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_EXPLOSIONS, 3);
            maxcap.addEnchantment(Enchantment.DURABILITY, 3);
            maxcap.addEnchantment(Enchantment.THORNS, 3);
            maxcap.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_FIRE, 3);
            maxcap.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_ENVIRONMENTAL, 3);
            maxcap.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_PROJECTILE, 3);
            maxleg.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_FALL, 3);
            maxleg.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_EXPLOSIONS, 3);
            maxleg.addEnchantment(Enchantment.THORNS, 3);
            maxleg.addEnchantment(Enchantment.DURABILITY, 3);
            maxleg.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_FIRE, 3);
            maxleg.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_ENVIRONMENTAL, 3);
            maxleg.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_PROJECTILE, 2);
            maxboots.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_FALL, 3);
            maxboots.addEnchantment(Enchantment.DURABILITY, 3);
            maxboots.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_EXPLOSIONS, 3);
            maxboots.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_FIRE, 3);
            maxboots.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_ENVIRONMENTAL, 3);
            maxboots.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_PROJECTILE, 3);
            maxboots.addEnchantment(Enchantment.THORNS, 3);
            zombie.getEquipment().setItemInHand(maxkardas);
            zombie.getEquipment().setHelmet(maxcap);
            zombie.getEquipment().setChestplate(maxchest);
            zombie.getEquipment().setLeggings(maxleg);
            zombie.getEquipment().setBoots(maxboots);
        
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a Minimal Reproducible Example

Comment: What are the zombies currently spawning with? Are they just vanilla zombies?

Comment: @lime yes, they are vannila zombies. I mean, they don't have any equipment on

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue might be in the order you're intializing `Zombie zombie = (Zombie) e.getEntity();`

Because you're doing it outsize the `if` for zombies, you might be forcing a mob to be a of type `Zombie` which might cause some issues.

I've moved `Zombie zombie = (Zombie) e.getEntity();` inside the `if` for zombies. Similar to your `if` for creepers.

Try the following:

```
public class ChargedCreepersIrZombiaiSuArmor extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
    }
    @EventHandler
    public void lol(CreatureSpawnEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getEntityType());
        if(e.getEntityType() == EntityType.CREEPER) {
            Creeper creeper = (Creeper) e.getEntity();
            creeper.setPowered(true);
        }

        if(e.getEntityType() == EntityType.ZOMBIE) {
            Zombie zombie = (Zombie) e.getEntity();
            ItemStack maxkardas = new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_SWORD);
            ItemStack maxcap = new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_HELMET);
            ItemStack maxleg = new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_LEGGINGS);
            ItemStack maxboots = new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_BOOTS);
            ItemStack maxchest = new  ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_CHESTPLATE);
            maxkardas.addEnchantment(Enchantment.FIRE_ASPECT, 3); 
            maxkardas.addEnchantment(Enchantment.DAMAGE_ALL, 3); 
            maxkardas.addEnchantment(Enchantment.DURABILITY, 3);
            maxchest.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_FALL, 3);
            maxchest.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_EXPLOSIONS, 3);
            maxchest.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_FIRE, 3);
            maxchest.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_ENVIRONMENTAL, 3);
            maxchest.addEnchantment(Enchantment.DURABILITY, 3);
            maxchest.addEnchantment(Enchantment.THORNS, 3);
            maxchest.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_PROJECTILE, 3);
            maxcap.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_FALL, 3);
            maxcap.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_EXPLOSIONS, 3);
            maxcap.addEnchantment(Enchantment.DURABILITY, 3);
            maxcap.addEnchantment(Enchantment.THORNS, 3);
            maxcap.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_FIRE, 3);
            maxcap.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_ENVIRONMENTAL, 3);
            maxcap.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_PROJECTILE, 3);
            maxleg.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_FALL, 3);
            maxleg.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_EXPLOSIONS, 3);
            maxleg.addEnchantment(Enchantment.THORNS, 3);
            maxleg.addEnchantment(Enchantment.DURABILITY, 3);
            maxleg.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_FIRE, 3);
            maxleg.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_ENVIRONMENTAL, 3);
            maxleg.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_PROJECTILE, 2);
            maxboots.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_FALL, 3);
            maxboots.addEnchantment(Enchantment.DURABILITY, 3);
            maxboots.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_EXPLOSIONS, 3);
            maxboots.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_FIRE, 3);
            maxboots.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_ENVIRONMENTAL, 3);
            maxboots.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_PROJECTILE, 3);
            maxboots.addEnchantment(Enchantment.THORNS, 3);
            zombie.getEquipment().setItemInHand(maxkardas);
            zombie.getEquipment().setHelmet(maxcap);
            zombie.getEquipment().setChestplate(maxchest);
            zombie.getEquipment().setLeggings(maxleg);
            zombie.getEquipment().setBoots(maxboots);
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if this solves your issue. If not, let me know what's happening and I can try and help again.

Comment: hey i tried your code but it did not work either :(.

Comment: @prigadiri Are you able to put `System.out.println(e.getEntityType());` right as you enter your `lol()` event handler? I'd like to see what the output is

Comment: uh, where i need to type that code? I'm sorry, i don't understand. I'm begginer btw :)

Comment: @prigadiri No worries, we all start somewhere! I'm just going to update this answer so you can copy and paste it. Let me know what the console says

Comment: ok i pasted i after public void, console shows only logs

Comment: @prigadiri I'm going to take a better look at this when I'm at home. For now, could you add the youtube video link to your description?

Comment: @prigadiri Hey. Sorry for the delay. Busy weekend. I'm just going to make a new answer but I'm going to need some more answers before I do so. Can you just try spawning a creeper. Does it spawn it as a charged creeper? If not, get rid of the zombie code and try again. Thanks

Comment: still nothing, deleted zombie code, they spawned not charged

Comment: look, i will try to solve this problem myself, i will let you know if its working. I will try to create new class and package and paste everything again.

Comment: @prigadiri Sorry. Again busy finishing up the school semester. I've been meaning to make a minecraft mod recently. Today's my last day, so once I'm done I'll try I'll look into it again. This is obviously doable, it's just a matter of sitting down in the proper environment to do it

Comment: hi, nevermind. I fixed my problem. Turns out my enchantment level was too high. Thank you anyways! Don't worry, you still helped me :).